# android studio 4.2.1 resolution reduction problem

Tags: android-studio-4.2

When I choose "Settings->Editor->Color Scheme" with the theme "Darcula copy", Android studio is very blurred on the extended monitor, and the resolution is obviously reduced.

My system is windows.

Comment: Check the cable of your monitor.

Comment: @majidhajibaba I upgraded before the version is 4.1.3, is no such problem, after the upgrade will appear, revert to 4.1.3 will be back to normal.